# javascript iframe unload

Tags: javascript, html, events, node.js, iframe

I have an iframe in my page , which this iframe is embedding a site which is not on my server.

I'm looking for a way to trigger a function before the iframe is redirecting to. for example when the user is clicking in a link inside the iframe and the iframe is redirecting , i want to trigger a function BEFORE it's redirecting.

i have this code so far:

```
document.getElementById("ifm").addEventListener("unload", trig());
function trig(){
    alert('2');
}
```

this code is alerting only once when the iframe is first loading.

i was trying also with the "onbeforeunload" event and it gives the same result.

question: how can i alerting BEFORE the iframe getting redirecting?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the trig function, so the return result is what is being passed to the addEventListener function.

Change your code to..

```
document.getElementById("ifm").addEventListener("unload", trig);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("ifm").addEventListener("unload", function() { trig(); });
```

Whether or not the iframe supports the unload event, that I don't know...

Thanks

Comment: the second code is trigger an the "trig" function only once when the page load at the first time and that's it. i want to trigger everytimr the iframe is been redirected. e.g. it's cross-domain.